# How to extract string using regular expression in c#

Tags: c#, regex

i have code like:

```
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/rukhsana/ontologies/2015/5/untitled-ontology-21#ہیز_پرائس">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/rukhsana/ontologies/2015/5/untitled-ontology-21#پرائس"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/rukhsana/ontologies/2015/5/untitled-ontology-21#پرائس_فار"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/rukhsana/ontologies/2015/5/untitled-ontology-21#کار_ایڈ"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

this is RDF/XML format for ontology. i want to extract ہیز_پرائس , پرائس_فار  using regular expression.  if any one can tell me regular expressions for tht.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/zH8jN0/1 .... or https://regex101.com/r/zH8jN0/2

Comment: This is XML, you should parse it with an XML parser, not with regex.

Comment: this is not simple XML ..its RDF/XML  so i cnt use simple Xml parser.

Comment: Do you want to extract text between '#' and '"' and join them with comma?

Answer (score 0):

try this expression:

(?<=#).*(?=\")

you can easily create regular expression using this site:

https://regex101.com/

Comment: It should be noted that this captures the preceding `#` and the trailing `"`. You would need to remove the first and last character from the captured string. [Regex 101 Link](https://regex101.com/r/zW9pU8/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = 
                "<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about=\"http://www.semanticweb.org/rukhsana/ontologies/2015/5/untitled-ontology-21#ہیز_پرائس\">" +
                      "<rdfs:range rdf:resource=\"http://www.semanticweb.org/rukhsana/ontologies/2015/5/untitled-ontology-21#پرائس\"/>" +    
                   "<owl:inverseOf rdf:resource=\"http://www.semanticweb.org/rukhsana/ontologies/2015/5/untitled-ontology-21#پرائس_فار\"/>" +
                      "<rdfs:domain rdf:resource=\"http://www.semanticweb.org/rukhsana/ontologies/2015/5/untitled-ontology-21#کار_ایڈ\"/>" +
                "</owl:ObjectProperty>";

            string pattern = ":(?'tag'[^=]+)=\"(?'url'[^#]+)#(?'arabic'[^\"]+)";

            Regex expr = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);

            MatchCollection matches = expr.Matches(input);
            foreach(Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("tag : {0}; url : {1}; arabic : {2}", match.Groups["tag"].Value, match.Groups["url"].Value, match.Groups["arabic"].Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to extract the arabic texts between '21#' and '"' and join them with comma, you can do Regex [Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var matches = String.Join(",", Regex
    // search for text between 21# and " using groups 
    .Matches(xml, "21#(.*?)\"")       
    // convert MatchCollection to IEnumerable
    .Cast<Match>()                    
    // select only the first group that will contain only required text.
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value));
```